# passing dynamic path in docker run command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to use this command in docker run

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v $(pwd)/php-docker/src:/var/www/html/ php-hello-world
```

but it is not working. Is there any way to use `pwd` in docker run

Comment: Why can't you just use `./` instead of `pwd`?

Comment: @mchawre, i tried that its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can use PWD, use it as variable `$PWD` instead subshell $(pwd)

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v $PWD/php-docker/src:/var/www/html/ php-hello-world
```